# Google Maps : Issue regarding marker icons and geocoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a jsp where i have converted the addresses into markers using geocoder class in google maps. Now the only problem i'm facing is that when i'm trying to change icon image for the marker, i'm only getting last icon for all the marker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;  
var address = new Array();  
var marker = new Array();  
var images=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"];  

function initialize()
{
var locations = new String("<%=request.getParameter("location")%>");  
locations=locations.substring(0,(locations.length)-1); 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), { 
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   zoom: 8
});

if(locations=='null' || locations=='')
    locations = 'Pune, INDIA\;';

address = locations.split('\;');

marker[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
    map:map 
});

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var i=1;
for(i=1; i<address.length; i++){
    geocoder.geocode({
          'address': address[i]+", India"
       },function(results, status){
          if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,  
                icon: 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker'+images[i]+'.png',
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: address[i]+', India'
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                info.open(map, marker);
            });
          }
       });
}
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address[0]+", India"
    },function(results, status){
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         marker[0].setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
         new google.maps.Circle({
             center: results[0].geometry.location,
             radius: radius * 1000,       // Convert to meters
             fillColor: '#00ff00',
             fillOpacity: 0.2,
             map: map,
             strokeColor : '#0000ff',
             strokeOpacity : 0.3,
             strokeWeight: 1
        });
     }
});
}//End of initialize function.  
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem (usually encountered with infowindows), it can be solved with function closure (a "createMarker" function is one option).

```
function createMarker(map, latlng, address, image) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,  
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker'+image+'.png',
            position: latlng
        });
        var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: address+', India'
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            info.open(map, marker);
        });
  return marker;
}
```

call it inside your loop like this:

```
geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address[i]+", India"
   },function(results, status){
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var marker = createMarker(results[0].geometry.location, address[i], images[i]);
      }
   });
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_geocodeCustomIconA.html) (the code you posted didn't behave as you described, includes function closure for the geocoding operation as well)

**UPDATE:**
You also need function closure on the address (a "geocodeAddress" function):

```
function geocodeAddress(map, address, i) {
   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address+", India"
   },function(results, status){
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    var marker = createMarker(map, results[0].geometry.location, address, images[i]);
      }
   });
}
```

So your processing loop becomes:

```
var i=1;
for(i=0; i<address.length; i++){
  geocodeAddress(map, address[i], i);
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var address = new Array();
var marker = new Array();
var images = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"];

function initialize() {
    var locations = 'Pune\;Mumbai\;';
    // locations=locations.substring(0,(locations.length)-1); 

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: 8
    });

    if (locations == 'null' || locations == '')
      locations = 'Pune, INDIA\;';

    address = locations.split('\;');

    marker[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var i = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
      geocodeAddress(map, address[i], i);
    }

    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address[0] + ", India"
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        //         marker[0].setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        new google.maps.Circle({
          center: results[0].geometry.location,
          radius: 1000, // radius * 1000,       // Convert to meters
          fillColor: '#00ff00',
          fillOpacity: 0.2,
          map: map,
          strokeColor: '#0000ff',
          strokeOpacity: 0.3,
          strokeWeight: 1
        });
      }
    });
  } //End of initialize function.  

function geocodeAddress(map, address, i) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address + ", India"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var marker = createMarker(map, results[0].geometry.location, address, images[i]);
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(map, latlng, address, image) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker' + image + '.png',
    position: latlng
  });
  var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: address + ', India'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    info.open(map, marker);
  });
  return marker;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```

Comment: Now that a new argument 'map' is being sent to createMaker, shouldn't we change the declaration of createMarker()? I have tried to use this but it doesn't seem to be working :(

Comment: Yup.  Sorry, never updated the code in the post from the ["working"/tested](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_geocodeCustomIconA.html) version.