# Google maps infowindow error f = undefined infowindow.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got a weird problem. It says f = undefined in infowindow.js. But I don't even have a file infowindow.js... This happens when I click on it. It has to show infowindow, but it doesn't.

Got the code from documentation here: [LINK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple-max)

Here's my code (**address array** is now adjusted, in my code there are **normal addresses** in it):

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: 52.3, lng: 5.7 }
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var addresses = [
        {
            'adres': 'teststraat 21',
            'plaats': 'Apeldoorn',
            'postcode': '1234AB',
            'telefoon': '0123456789',
            'openingstijden': 'test'
        },
        {
            'adres': 'teststraat 21',
            'plaats': 'Apeldoorn',
            'postcode': '1234AB',
            'telefoon': '0123456789',
            'openingstijden': 'test'
        },
        {
            'adres': 'teststraat 21',
            'plaats': 'Apeldoorn',
            'postcode': '1234AB',
            'telefoon': '0123456789',
            'openingstijden': 'test'
        },
    ];

    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, addresses);
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, addresses) {
    for(var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': addresses[i]['adres'] + addresses[i]['plaats']}, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var counter = i - addresses.length;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'test',
                    maxWidth: 200
                });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: resultsMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: 'testadres ' + addresses[counter]['plaats'],
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                i++;
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The example on google - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse - has them declaring the `infowindow` outside of the geocoder? Maybe take a look at that

Comment: How do you include Google Maps API in your code?

Comment: I get a `status` of `ZERO_RESULTS` on all those geocodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps : Issue regarding marker icons and geocoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918811/google-maps-issue-regarding-marker-icons-and-geocoding)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps : Issue regarding marker icons and geocoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918811/google-maps-issue-regarding-marker-icons-and-geocoding)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps infowindow don't work on marker click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301044/google-maps-infowindow-dont-work-on-marker-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `map` instead of `resultsMap` in this piece of code:

The `map` object doesn't exist in this context. Should be:

```
infowindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
```

To close the staying `infowindow` before opening a new one, add only one `infowindow` instance and change it's content and position on marker click:

```js
var infowindow = null;
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: { lat: 52.3, lng: 5.7 }
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var addresses = [];

    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map, addresses);
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap, addresses) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for(var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': addresses[i]['adres'] + " " + addresses[i]['plaats']}, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var counter = i - addresses.length;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: resultsMap,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: 'testadres ' + addresses[counter]['plaats'],
                });
                marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent('test content');
                    infowindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
                });
                i++;
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="height:400px; width:500px;"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can close the current opened infowindow when I click another window?

Comment: Add var infowindow = null as global variable, intialize it using infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'test',
                    maxWidth: 200
                }); inside initMap and change the listener code: marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent('mycontent');
                    infowindow.open(resultsMap, marker);
                }); 
So you would have only one infowindow instance for whole project, you will just be changing it's content and opening it on different place.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks ;) Did not instantiate it in initmap but in geocoder function, but works :D

Comment: Your edit wouldn't work, because you use var infowindow = .. inside geocodeAddress which would create local instane of infowindow for every geocode result. Plus one instance of infowindow is really enough, so just put it inside initMap.